# $G \times H$ regular $\implies G $ and $H$ regular?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, products

I know that if two graphs $G,H$ are regular then their Cartesian product is also regular. But I never heard of the veracity of the converse. Is is true ? I think yes by the following argument but I am not sure :

We can show the contrapositive : If $G$ or $H$ is not regular then (wlog) we can assume $G$ is not regular then there exists two vertices $g_1,g_2 \in V(G)$ such that $n=\deg(g_1)\neq \deg(g_2) =m$. Then let $h \in H$, we have in $G \times H$ :
$$\deg (g_1,v)=n+\deg(v)\neq\deg (g_2,v)=m+\deg(v)$$

So $G \times H$ is not regular. Is it correct ? I also noticed that if we assume a property on $G$ and $H$ then $G \times H$ also verifies it (for example $G,H$ bipartite $\iff G \times H$ bipartite), is there a counterexample for that ?

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. As for your second question, what about the property of being a [semi-Eulerian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)? Let $G$ be a cycle with three edges and $H$ be a single-edge graph. $G\times H$ looks like the graph of edges of a triangular prism, and all six vertices have a degree $3$, so there is no path traversing all edges once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is correct (except you switched from $h$ to $v$).

A counterexample is given by planarity – for instance, the [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) $Q_n$ is planar exactly if $n\le3$, so planarity is not inherited in $Q_4\cong Q_1\times Q_3\cong Q_2\times Q_2$.